# Javascript creates dynamic html input not staying after form submission

Tags: javascript, php, html

Here is my code.

```
<form action="" method ="get">
    <script type="text/javascript">
            function showDateInputs(timeValue){
                
                var oldDiv = document.getElementById("newDiv");
                //alert(timeValue);
                if (oldDiv != null){
                        oldDiv.parentNode.removeChild(oldDiv);
                }
                
                var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
                newDiv.setAttribute("id", "newDiv");
                newDiv.setAttribute("style", "display: inline;");
                if (timeValue == 1){
                    //alert("no way");
                    newDiv.innerHTML = "Start Date <input type='date' name='start' id='start' value='<?php echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 year')); ?>' min='2018-01-02' max='<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>'> End Date <input type='date' name='end' id='end' value='<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>' min='2018-01-03' max='<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>'>";
                    document.getElementById('timeInputs').appendChild(newDiv);
                }
                else if (timeValue == 2){
                    //alert("yes way");
                    newDiv.innerHTML = "Select Week <input type='week' name='start' id='start' value='<?php echo date('Y').'-W'.date('W'); ?>' min='2018-W01' max='<?php echo date('Y').'-W'.date('W'); ?>'>";
                    document.getElementById('timeInputs').appendChild(newDiv);
                }
            }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function showDateInputsWeek(timeValue){
            if (timeValue == 2) {
                var oldDiv = document.getElementById("newDiv");
                //alert(timeValue);
                if (oldDiv != null){
                        oldDiv.parentNode.removeChild(oldDiv);
                }

                var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
                newDiv.setAttribute("id", "newDiv");
                newDiv.setAttribute("style", "display: inline;");

                //alert("yes way");
                newDiv.innerHTML = "Select Week <input type='week' name='start' id='start' value='<?php echo $_GET['start']; ?>' min='2018-W01' max='<?php echo date('Y').'-W'.date('W'); ?>'>";
                document.getElementById('timeInputs').appendChild(newDiv);
            }               
        }

    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function showDateInputsRange(timeValue){
            if (timeValue == 1) {
                var oldDiv = document.getElementById("newDiv");
                //alert(timeValue);
                if (oldDiv != null){
                        oldDiv.parentNode.removeChild(oldDiv);
                }

                var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
                newDiv.setAttribute("id", "newDiv");
                newDiv.setAttribute("style", "display: inline;");

                //alert("no way");
                newDiv.innerHTML = "Start Date <input type='date' name='start' id='start' value='<?php echo $_GET['start']; ?>' min='2018-01-02' max='<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>'> End Date <input type='date' name='end' id='end' value='<?php echo $_GET['end']; ?>' min='2018-01-03' max='<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>'>";
                document.getElementById('timeInputs').appendChild(newDiv);
            }           
        }
    </script>
    

    <label for="timePeriod">Utilization Hours:</label>
    <div id="timeInputs" style="display: inline">
        <select name="timePeriod"  id="timePeriod" onchange="showDateInputs(value)">
            <option value="4">past 4 Hours</option>
            <option value="8">past 8 Hours</option>
            <option value="16">past 16 Hours</option>
            <option selected value="24" >past 24 Hours</option>
            <option value="1">select range</option>
            <option value="2">select week</option>
        </select>
    
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">

  <script type="text/javascript">
      

      document.getElementById('timePeriod').value = "<?php echo $_GET['timePeriod'];?>";
      showDateInputsRange(document.getElementById('timePeriod').value);
      showDateInputsWeek(document.getElementById('timePeriod').value);
  </script> 
</form>
```

I have showDateInputs(timeValue) to create the date inputs for an onchange of a select form. I had the other 2 functions as one, but it was only working for one case so I tried to separate them so some detail of Javascript that I did not know would not affect the code.

Currently, everything besides the week input works as intended. All options stay as the selected option after the form and set the appropiate url paramaters. The range dynamically created date inputs also stay after the submit button is hit. The thing I am stuck on is that the week input does not stay after submission. I think it might be in how I set the inner html of the week input.
[image: Snipet of how my page looks after a week is submitted.]

As you can see in this picture, the week input is no longer visible after the submit button is pressed. The range option date inputs do stay after the submit button is pressed.

Comment: dynamically generated content will not persist over page loads. The fact that SOME content appears to persist is because you explicitly call `showDateInputsRange` and `showDateInputsWeek`

Comment: How is this a "php" question?

Comment: I put "php" because I use the <?php echo ?> a lot for getting values and was unsure if that could have been the issue. @FunkFortyNiner

Comment: Professor Abronsius, That is the question. The showDataInputsRange lets the range persist, but the showDateInputsWeek is not letting the week select persist. That is what I am trying to do. @ProfessorAbronsius

Comment: To keep it all javascript you could store the new structure in `sessionStorage` and use that to rebuild on page reload

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius do you know why what I was already trying is not working how I think it should?

Comment: if you submit the form you rebuild the original page - that original page does not feature the content added dynamically. You can either, as already suggested, use AJAX to send the request and thus not need to `rebuild` the page or find some means by which you store the newly generated content and use that save content to rebuild the display when the page reloads.

Comment: @Byrge Well, it's hard to know what the problem since I'm so not a JS guy, so I wouldn't be of much help there. If this is a "php" issue, then all I can suggest is to see if there are any php errors by enabling error reporting, looking at the HTML source and `var_dump()`'ing to see what shows or not.

Answer (score 0):

This is totally logical, because the form refreshes the DOM after submit, u need to prevent the submission of your form from refreshing the DOM by using :

```
$("#form_ID").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Make sure to add an HTML  tag to contain your form.

Also, you can add a JS method to handle the form submit action :

```
var form = document.getElementById("form_ID");
function handleFormSubmit(event) { 
    event.preventDefault(); 
} 
form.addEventListener('submit', handleFormSubmission());
```

Comment: I am not trying to prevent my form from submitting. I need it to put the variables in the URL and I need it to submit. I have a function that runs when its submitted to see if it is either week or range and then keeps their newly created inputs. The range portion works but not the week one. I do not see how preventing a submissions helps here.

Comment: Neither is @Rayen, its just you will have to submit your form through ajax, that will allow the form to retain its current data, and still submit it. Otherwise an actual form submission will refresh the page, causing all the dynamic content to have to be regenerated.   Alternatively you can return the values you want and have your php code listen for it and force it to populate your dynamically generated content, but this will not be automatic.

Comment: @Danimal thank you for the clarification. I am sure it is obvious at this point that this is my first time using Javascript. I believe I am attempting your second point with my showDataInputsRange and showDataInputsWeek. I have above in php an isset(submit) to update the php global with what is set by the form.

Comment: @Danimal, there is two approaches : 
1- By using ```event.preventDefault()``` you can call another method that contains the logic to execute for form submission. Or you can use ajax as u said.
@Byrge, as I said you will call another method to submit the form data to your custom URL. It really depends on your need and the logic behind. 
Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

So I understand my approach is not as ideal as the AJAX solution, but I figured out why my showDateInputsRange() worked while my showDateInputsWeek() did not. When it is was a week input there was no end variable in the URL and because I call both functions each time, the showDateInputsRange() function would throw an error because there was no variable named 'end' that is was trying to fetch.

Comment: Have you solved your problem now satisfactorily do you think?

Comment: Yeah I just slapped an if depending on which case so it no longer calls the function that needs end to be in the url when it is not there. That fixed it. @ProfessorAbronsius